# On an integral inequality involving the characteristic function (probabilistic setting).

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, probability-theory

I am following *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley

[image]

Could someone give me a couple of steps on how the above inequality was found?

Comment: You haven't copied formula  (26.2)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $(26.3)$ we have$$
\left|e^{ix}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\right|=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\left| \int_0^x(x-s)^{n-1}(e^{is}-1) ds\right|.$$ 
We estimate $\left| \int_0^x(x-s)^{n-1}(e^{is}-1) ds\right|$ in the cases $x\ge 0$ and $x<0$ separately.
$(1)$ $x\ge 0$.
\begin{align}
\left| \int_0^x (x-s)^{n-1}(e^{is}-1) ds\right|&\le\int_0^x(x-s)^{n-1}|e^{is}-1| ds\\
&\le 2\int_0^x (x-s)^{n-1} ds\quad (\text{since}\; |e^{is}-1|\le 2)\\
&=\frac{2}{\,n\,}x^n=\frac{2}{\,n\,}|x|^n.\end{align}
$(2)$ $x<0.\;\;$   Since $$
 \int_0^x(x-s)^{n-1}(e^{is}-1) ds=-\int_0^{|x|}(-|x|+t)^{n-1}(e^{-it}-1) dt\quad (t=-s),$$

we have \begin{align}
\left|\int_0^x(x-s)^{n-1}(e^{is}-1) ds\right|&=\left|-\int_0^{|x|}(-|x|+t)^{n-1}(e^{-it}-1) dt\right|\\
&\le 2\int_0^{|x|}(|x|-t)^{n-1} dt=\frac{2}{\,n\,}|x|^n.\end{align}
Therefore we have in both cases$$
\left|e^{ix}-\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(ix)^k}{k!}\right|\le \frac{2}{n!}|x|^n.$$